# Applying formulas in excel python

Tags: python, excel

So I download reports and they come in as a CSV format. From my understanding for python to interact with excel, the files have to be in XLSX format. This part I have down.

However I'm having issues with applying formulas and macros that I've created in excel to the current sheet.

Basically I want it to both apply formulas such as =vlookup('insert stuff here') on say like A2 and have it do the same for A3, A4,... until the last row along with applying excel macros such as pressing "Ctrl + T" (an excel macro I created).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=formulas+excel+python

Comment: If you include the code you have so far and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're stuck on, you'll be much more likely to get answers.